# AJAX only works from Default.aspx, but not in any other page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I have a very simple form that I am using in a web forms website.  The form is embedded in an ascx control and it is re-used throughout the site in various pages.  It was working fine until we decided to implement server-side validation using an ajax postback.  So, I added update panels and triggers and everything works fine if I use the form from my Default.aspx form, but it doesn't work from any other page.  I have been googling this for two days and so far I cannot figure out if this is an ASPX problem, or if it is an IIS configuration problem.  I am very much stuck.

This is the form ( it is incredibly simple ).  The form resides in an ASCX user control

```html
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="AllFormFields" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" placeholder="E-Mail" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" placeholder="Phone" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="rcbPrimarySpecialty" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Primary Specialty"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" placeholder="Comments"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Request Info" CausesValidation="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ValidationMessagePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblValidationMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

The idea is that the user clicks the button btnSubmit and ajax calls its click handler.

When I use the site under my VS debugger, the click handler is not even called.  Something else is interfering with the Ajax call and the postback never happens.

Comment: have you put a scriptmanager control?

Comment: Yes, it is in my master page, so every page gets it.  I tried adding another script manager inside the ASCX control and I get an error saying there was already a script manager in the page.  So I know for sure that is not the cause.